# Making main widget resize with window in Qt Creator using PySide2

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator, pyside2

Like the title says, I'm designing a layout in Qt Creator and I want the main widget to resize dynamically with the window. I am not able to achieve this.

I have already found endless posts where the only solution they give is giving the central widget a layout (for which you first need to add a child) and setting the size policy to Expanding. I have already tried this.

Next I show two different minimum examples.

### Example 1

First, I create a new project of type "Application (Qt for Python)" > "Qt for Python - Window (UI file)", with base class `QWidget`.

I then add two Text Edit widgets in the Designer view. I right click the root widget and choose "Lay out" > "Lay out vertically". Finally, I set the root widget horizontal and vertical resize policy to "Expanding". This is the resulting Designer window:

[image: The resulting Designer window for example 1, showing a root widget with two text edit widgets as children, laid out vertically, with size policy Expanding]

This is the `widget.py` file:

```py
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run the `widget.py` file, I get the following result:

[image: Result for example 1: the window show the two text inputs but they do not resize with the window]

As you can see, the two text edit fields are visible but they do not resize with the window.

### Example 2

First, I create a new project of type "Application (Qt for Python)" > "Qt for Python - Window (UI file)", with base class `QMainWindow`.

I then add two Text Edit widgets in the Designer view. I right click the main window and choose "Lay out" > "Lay out vertically". Finally, I set the central widget horizontal and vertical resize policy to "Expanding". This is the resulting Designer window:

[image: The resulting Designer window for example 2, showing a main window with a central widget with two text edit widgets as children, laid out vertically, with size policy Expanding]

This is the `mainwindow.py` file:

```py
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run the `mainwindow.py` file, I get the following result:

[image: Result for example 2: the window is empty]

In this case nothing appears in the window, it is completely empty. I have also tried setting the size policy of the window (instead of the widget) itself to Expanding (and also setting both), with the same result.

I'm using Python 3.10, PySide 2, Qt 5.15.3 and Qt Creator 7.0.0

Comment: Do the first, but inherit from QMainWindow, then call `setCentralWidget()` with the object returned by `loader.load()`.

Comment: @musicamante Actually, just substituting the parent class from `QWidget` to `QMainWindow` worked! Any idea of what the problem with both examples was? I also tried to `self.setCentralWidget(widget)` (`widget` being the object returned by `loader.load(ui_file, self)`) like you said and it made no difference, it worked too without any errors.

Comment: It seems that QUiLoader (or, to be precise, QAbstractFormBuilder) automatically sets the top widget as the central widget if the parent is a QMainWindow that has no central widget set yet. Both problems are caused by the fact that QUiLoader always create a new widget (unlike the `uic` module of PyQt, which is able to "set up" an existing widget with the ui data). In the first case, you just created a "floating" widget that is a child of `Widget`, which is the same as creating a child widget without adding it to a layout (the fact that the child widget has a layout is irrelevant).

Comment: For the second case, I actually don't know: you said that just inheriting from QMainWindow instead of QWidget was enough, which is exactly what you're doing there. Did you change anything else?

Comment: @musicamante Nope, just changing that single thing was able to fix it. I ended up doing everything you said, just for good measure. If you can post this as an answer I'll make sure to mark it as solved.

Comment: Then how comes that in your question your second example didn't already work? The only difference between them is the inheritance, so if it now works, it should have had before too. Maybe you used two different ui files?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, the UI files were different. I didn't post the files themselves, but in the screenshots you can see the difference in the Design view of QtCreator

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that in the second one you've actually created a main window ui.